# Are App Store in-app purchases refundable?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

If the user makes in-app purchase in an iOS application, is it possible to to request a refund in the application itself? Does Apple allow this?

Comment: Refunds *are* possible, but only through a request between the person associated with the Apple ID account and Apple. What *isn't* possible is for your app to issue purchases. In addition to @Jim_Bray answer, if your concern is an accidental purchase, add a prompt/popup confirming with the user that they wish to purchase *before* using StoreKit.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible. However, if you’re worried about accidental purchases, you can always place a link to this page somewhere in your app. [Request A Refund from App Store](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204084)

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible if the iOS app is running on iOS 15+.**

A new function named [beginRefundRequest(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3803220-beginrefundrequest/) was added to StoreKit in iOS 15.0+.
By calling this from within the app (e.g., from the Account Settings or Help menu), the system will display the following refund request sheet. On this sheet, you can select the Refund Request item and request a refund.

[image]